# Julia: Sample from a custom distribution and perform an in-place update

Tags: julia

I know how to use `randn!` to sample from the standard normal distribution and perform an in-place update. For example,

```
rng = MersenneTwister(1234);
A = zeros(5);
randn!(rng, A)
```

updates `A` with five numbers sampled from the standard normal.

However, suppose I used `Distributions.jl` and created a custom distribution, called `dist`. I know how to sample from it using `rand`, but it does not perform an in-place update. If I need to repeatedly sample from `dist` and store the values in `A`, I would end up with a huge memory allocation. Is there a function like `randn!` that allows me to sample from a custom distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
julia> using Random, Distributions

julia> dist = Poisson(1.0)
Poisson{Float64}(λ=1.0)

julia> rng = MersenneTwister(1234);

julia> x = rand(rng, dist, 5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0

julia> rand!(rng, dist, x)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 3
 0
 4
```

note the help of `rand!`:

> `rand!(::AbstractRNG, ::Sampleable, ::AbstractArray)`
>
> Samples in-place from the sampler and stores the result in the provided array.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `rand!` approach, it is possible to use broadcasting:

```
A .= rand.(dist)
```